# Use cases of instance initializer

Tags: java, oop

I know instance initializers will be called before my constructor, and they are like static constructors, only that they are called everytime I create an instance of the class. E.g.

```
public class App {    
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        new App();
        new App();
    }

    static{
        System.out.println( "static initializer" );
    }

    public App(){
        System.out.println( "constructor" );
    }

    {
        System.out.println( "instance initializer" );
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
static initializer
instance initializer
constructor
instance initializer
constructor
```

But why should I ever use them? I just could write the logic in my constructor, and if I want to do the logic before some already existing constructor I could just add it to the beginning of the constructor.

I also see no advantage on inherited classes, because even if I overwrite the constructor I can still just implement own logic and call the parents constructor afterwards.

What is a proper use case for instance initializers in Java, or any language at all? Or is it always possible to get the same functionallity with constructors?

Comment: There may cases where you declared a Util class and want to access a static util method in a constructor for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [JLS 8.6 - Instance Initializers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.6):

> An instance initializer declared in a class is executed when an instance of the class is created.

From the [JLS 8.8 - Constructor Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8):

> A constructor is used in the creation of an object that is an instance of a class.

Thus confirming your point that everything that gets done in instance initializers can also be done in your constructor.

This leaves proximity. Compare:

```
Map<String, String> lookup = new HashMap<>();

{
    lookup.put("Hello", "Hello");
}
```

with:

```
Map<String, String> lookup = new HashMap<>();

// Maybe some considerable number of lines of code.
public Test() {
    lookup.put("Hello", "Hello");
}
```

There is clearly no functional difference between these two but putting the two closer together makes sense.

Of course there is the edge case of:

```
public Test() throws Exception {
   // ...
}
```

which you cannot do in an instance initialiser.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple constructors, instance initializers will also be executed.
That way you don't have to copy-paste code.

Answer (score 0):

I used it couple of times when i make a customized anonymous class instances where you can't explicitly declare a constructor.
[see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5.1)

For example,

```
public static final Set<String> someStringSet =  new HashSet<String>(){
    {
    add("string1");  
    add("string2");
    add("string3");
    }
};
```

It can be an anonymous hashmap or anything you can think of that needs to be modified 
at the beginning.